# Syntax Error: "(" unexpected error on XAMPP installation

Tags: software-installation, xampp

I'm getting these errors while running `sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-7.3.7-1-installer.run`.

```
$ sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-7.3.7-1-installer.run`
./xampp-linux-x64-7.3.7-1-installer.run: 1: ./xampp-linux-x64-7.3.7-1-installer.run: ELF: not found
./xampp-linux-x64-7.3.7-1-installer.run: 2: ./xampp-linux-x64-7.3.7-1-installer.run: @@@0@00088@8@00��#��#�#�c������#��c��c��TT@T@: not found
./xampp-linux-x64-7.3.7-1-installer.run: 6: ./xampp-linux-x64-7.3.7-1-installer.run: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

Output of  `uname -a`:

```
Linux ows-desktop 4.15.0-1032-raspi2 #34-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Feb 6 11:46:23 UTC 2019 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

I also tried downloading and running 32 bit version of XAMPP> But this is what I got:

```
$ sudo ./xampp-linux-5.6.20-0-installer.run
./xampp-linux-5.6.20-0-installer.run: 1: ./xampp-linux-5.6.20-0-installer.run: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Comment: Please do not use images what is supposed to be text. copy/paste the notices. And the error seems to indicate you are using the wrong installation file with the 1st one. The 2nd one might be because of a wrong environment. What is the 1st line in the file? If not bash/dash you need to switch shell. Also consider to use native LAMP instead of 3rd party installations. The native one install rather smooth :)

Comment: Sounds like you have downloaded the wrong file. Can you show us the output of i) `file xampp-linux-x64-7.3.7-1-installer.run` and, if that says it is a text file,  `head xampp-linux-x64-7.3.7-1-installer.run`?

Comment: The "("  unexpected error cause you have wrong filename instead  a wrong file, try to rename it with `Xampp_installer.rum`. That should be works

Comment: You mention using `uname -a` but don't actually provide its output. Please [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks for the comment, I was edited my question. What do u mean by wrong installation file. I am using xamp-linux-x64 version and for x32bit I'm using the old version that support 32bit. Am I wrong? I was switched to downloads folder bcs my file is inside this folder.

Comment: @steeldriver thanks. I was edited and inserted the output of uname -a. Is x64 or x32bit?

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri thanks, this is the output:                                    
 ows@ows-desktop:~/Downloads$ file xampp-linux-x64-7.3.7-1-installer.run

xampp-linux-x64-7.3.7-1-installer.run: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, for GNU/Linux 2.4.0, stripped

Comment: OK so the issue is not a matter of 32 verus 64 bit - it is that you are trying to execute an Intel/AMD (x86) binary on an ARM (aarch64) processor

Comment: @steeldriver okay thanks. So, is it possible to install xampp to this or how to solve this?

Comment: That depends: does xampp support ARM?

Comment: @steeldriver Would you like to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks!!! +1.

Answer (score 2):

According to your `uname` output, your processor architecture is [aarch64](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/arm/aarch64) - which is 64-bit ARM

However according to `file`, the installer that you are trying to run is ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64 which is for the 64-bit AMD/Intel instruction set.

Because the kernel doesn't know how to load and execute the code, it make a last-ditch attempt to execute it with the default shell interpreter - which fails with a syntax error, as you have observed.

See also:

- [Syntax error: “(” unexpected when execute a compiled c program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336436/syntax-error-unexpected-when-execute-a-compiled-c-program)

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-*-installer.run

sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-*-installer.run
```

Comment: Some explanation why this should help would be nice.